# IF $a is TRUE and $b is NOT TRUE

Tags: php, if-statement, boolean

Ok, there is a good chance I'm not explaining this correctly but I hope I can make sense. I'm fairly inexperienced with PHP and am trying to wrap my head around how to write this statement.

I have two string values, $string_a and $string_b. I want it do something if $string_a has a value. But I don't want it to do something if $string_b has a value.

Example:

`IF $string_a { do something }`

`IF $string_b { do nothing }`

`IF $string_a and $string_b { do nothing }`

I know I'm just thinking about this all wrong... Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want something like:

```
<?php
if( $a && !$b ){
// Do something
}
?>
```

Comment: Cool, I think this is what I'm looking for. Haha... I think. I don't know if I explained my logic correctly but this seems to be working so I'm not ognna complain.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(strlen($a) && !strlen($b)){
    //a and not b
}

if(!strlen($a) && !strlen($b)){
    //not a and not b
}

if(strlen($a) && strlen($b)){
    // a and  b
}
```

Etcetera etcetera....

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!empty($string_a) && empty($string_b)) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to think how to implement the conditions :
Do you really want to ONLY do an action when string_a has the value ?

Example :

```
if($string_a == "thevalue" AND $string_b != "thebadvalueofb") { this code will do something }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

`if ( ($string_a) and (not ($string_b)) )`

You don't really need all those parens, I just want to make it clear what's happening here.

Answer (score -1):

if($string_a!="" && string_b=""))
{
do something

}

if string_ a is not empty and string_b is empty do something. no need for an else